# Javascript: Is there a way to use a string as a callback without eval()?

Tags: javascript, string, callback, eval

So I need to make make a callback in one of my functions, but due to the way the whole program is working, I need to pass the callback function name in the form of a string rather than the function itself.

For example:

```
function doThings(callback){
    alert('hello');
    eval(callback + '();');
}

function test(){
    alert('world!');
}

var func = 'test';

doThings(func);
```

In short, I'm trying to dynamically change which function is used, and I have to use a string to represent the callback function rather than an actual function reference.

I keep reading eval is evil - is there any way to do this without `eval()`?

EDIT: I do not have the ability to list out the functions in an object beforehand. I also need to pass an array as individual arguments to this function, and for some reason `.apply()` doesn't get along well with `window[callback]()`

Comment: Which environment are you in? In a browser you might do doThings(window[func]), window['test']() etc., so you can access the function by name from the parent scope object.

Comment: @DevDig It's in browser. I tried that, but doing window[func]().apply(null, args) doesn't work. I should have mentioned that earlier. I need to also pass an array as individual arguments to the function.

With that said, is it necessarily insecure to use eval() if I'm limiting all of the variables in it to being alphanumeric? How is this less secure than say generating SQL and sanitizing inputs?

Comment: window[func]() should do the trick as well as window[func].apply(null, args). Some informations about evil eval: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/

Answer (score 9):

You can do this, in this way.

```js
function doThings(callback){
    alert('hello');
    window[callback]();
}

function test(){
    alert('world!');
}

var func = 'test';

doThings(func);
```

Or you can pass the full function in string and use the `Function` constructor.

```js
function doThings(callback){
    alert('hello');
    (new Function('return '+callback)())();
}

function test(){
    alert('world!');
}

var func = test.toString();

doThings(func);
```

Comment: Updated, it was a previous test, forgot to remove it ;)

Comment: I was about to post the exact same solution.  It's probably worth mentioning (if not vastly important) that the callback functions will need to have global scope in order for this to work, though.

Comment: I tried the first one already, but in my code I needed to use apply() so I could pass an array to the callback as individual arguments.

I like the second one though. I think I'll try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Store the functions in an object. Use the property names to access them.

```js
function doThings(callback) {
  alert('hello');
  my_possible_functions[callback]();
}

function test() {
  alert('world!');
}

var my_possible_functions = {};
my_possible_functions.test = test;


var func = 'test';
doThings(func);
```

Comment: In my current situation I don't have the ability to list out all of the functions in an object like that unfortunately.

Comment: @Archer I guess we upvoted for idea. Yes there was a typo, but i guess Idea is more important

Comment: One can also use a shortcut `var my_possible_functions = { test };`

Answer (score 0):

A very similar answer to @[Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin)'s but with additional checks

- Check if its a part of current Object
- Check if value is of type `function`. If value is not a function, it will break your code.

```js
function doThings(callback) {
  console.log('hello ', callback);
  try {
    callbackList[callback]()
  } catch (ex) { 
    console.log(ex.message)
  }
  
  callbackList.hasOwnProperty(callback) && typeof(callbackList[callback]) === 'function' && callbackList[callback]()
}

Object.prototype.test3 = function() {
  console.log("this should not be called");
}

var callbackList = {
  test: function test() {
    console.log('world!');
  },
  test2: "World"
}

doThings('test');
doThings("test2");
doThings("test3");
```

Comment: I don't have the ability in my situation to make an object filled with callbacks.